# how do i deal with the queue front and pop function

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, stl, queue

i read in the c++ reference and in the queue header file that the queue.front() function returns a reference.
queue.pop() seems to delete that element in the queue.

in my case the queue stores strings (messages) there is a class who stores some strings in the queue and some threads call a function which looks like that

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&this->mutex);

while(this->TEMP.size() == 0){
    usleep(10);
}

string line;



line = this->TEMP.front();

this->TEMP.pop();

pthread_mutex_unlock(&this->mutex);
return line;;
}
```

so if it is a reference the thread which calls that function will die or something horrible happens because the memory gets freed with pop before.

Am i right so far???

so how am i going to do that???

Comment: In C++, it's good style to define a variable and immediately assign it an initial value: `std::string line = TEMP.front()`. No need to first create an empty string and then overwrite it.

Comment: Why are you sleeping while holding the mutex? How can any other thread change `this->TEMP.size()` while you hold a lock on it?

Comment: IIRC you're supposed to use condition variables for that. (Not sure, i don't use pthreads)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `line.operator=(std::string& source)`. The reference `source` is initialized from the reference returned by `TEMP.front()`. Once that operator returns, the assignment is done. You now have two copies of the string. After `.pop`, the original is gone, but `line` still holds its value.